# Undesired very fine at local mesh when using detect_features

Tags: cgal

Dear users and developers,

Is there a way to avoid the mesh from becoming extremely fine at certain locations (see attached Fig. 1) when using "CGAL::make_mesh_3" to mesh an object for which "detect_features" is used to automatically detect edges?

I have tried by varying the protection angles but given that the angle of the edge to be detected varies significantly there are always locations with the issue mentioned. With another mesher I managed to keep this from happening by setting a lower bound on the size of the triangles and tetrahedra conforming the mesh, but in CGAL from what I can tell I can only specify upper bounds.

Regards,
Tim

[Fig. 1: Undesired mesh refinement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDvL0.png)

Comment: My guess is that where the mesh is overrefined, a feature should have been protected but it is not. Were you able to visualize the graph of feature to be protected?

Comment: That is indeed what is happening. But it is not really feasible for my cases to manually specify the edges to avoid this from happening (and the automatic detection is simply not capable of this due to the extreme angles, so to say, at those locations. That's why I am wondering if there is a way to at least avoid having those very small elements (even if the edges are not properly preserved at those specific locations).

Comment: The mesh got refined because we ask for a "high" precision and since it cannot put a vertex exactly on the vertex/edge (which is what the protection is doing) there is no other way for the mesher to please the approximation error criteria. In this case, we should tell the mesher that the size criteria should prevail on the approximation error. I'll have to check how this can be done.

Comment: @sloriot Any updates as I am still looking for a solution to this issue